# using Google maps api on android- fee for use?

Tags: android, gps

I want to use google map link on my android application.

here is a link to the application i am doing.

[Review of app on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYizB-Msj7E)

Can I make this a paid app for .99$ on google play without paying a fee or attaining a license to use google maps?

Answer (score 0):

Google charges it users based on number of requests a user/ application make request to its api you can find the price calculator for different api provided by google[here](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/#sup_1)

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+------------+
|      Name of Google API           | No Free Request Per Day |
+-----------------------------------+------------+-------------+
| Javascript API                    |      20,000             |
|                                   |                         |
| Geo-Coding API                    |      2,500              |
|                                   |                         |
| Static Maps API                   |      20,000             |
|                                   |                         |
| Geo-Coding API                    |      2,500              |
|                                   |                         |
| Directions API                    |      2500               | 
|                                   |                         |
| Geo-Coding API                    |      2,500              |
+-----------------------------------+------------+------------+
```

As per google website Google Map API for android is free for use there is no limit to the number of request you make you can check pricing information and tutorials to work on an android app [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/)

If you are planning to sell the APP you have to contact the Google Map Division to get the details about how much you have to pay for the usage.

Comment: thanks for the reply:)  I will contact google about this.